# Cubic spline in cython

Tags: python, performance, cython

For several projects I need a way to use cubic splines inside cythonized functions and since the `scipy` functions cannot be used within `cython`, I went out and built my own. I would like some suggestions and comments, if possible. My goals are:

- Be able to *call* the cubic spline (after initialization) as efficiently as possible. Currently this is 4 times slower (with `cython`) compared to equivalent `numba` implementation.
- Be able to pass arrays of floats as well as single floats.
- Be able to *initialize* the spline as efficiently as possible (for cases where I need to construct splines multiple times).

Here is the code I have written (based on another code from years ago, which I do not remember how I got) (`interp.pyx`)

```
import cython

cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.profile(False)
cpdef tuple calculate_spline_params(
    double[:] x,
    double[:] y,
):
    cdef:
        int n = x.size - 1
        double[:] a = y.copy()
        double[:] b = np.zeros(n)
        double[:] c = np.zeros(n+1)
        double[:] d = np.zeros(n)
        double[:] h = np.diff(x)
        double[:] alpha = np.zeros(n-1)
        double[:] ell = np.ones(n+1)
        double[:] mu = np.zeros(n)
        double[:] z = np.zeros(n+1)
    
    for i in range(0, n-1):
        alpha[i] = 3 * ((a[i+2] - a[i+1]) / h[i+1] - (a[i+1] - a[i]) / h[i])
    
    for i in range(1, n):
        ell[i] = 2 * (x[i+1] - x[i-1]) - h[i-1] * mu[i-1]
        mu[i] = h[i] / ell[i]
        z[i] = (alpha[i-1] - h[i-1] * z[i-1]) / ell[i]

    for i in range(n-1, -1, -1):
        c[i] = z[i] - mu[i] * c[i+1]
    
    for i in range(0, n):
        b[i] = (a[i+1] - a[i]) / h[i] + (c[i] + 2 * c[i+1]) * h[i] / 3
        d[i] = (c[i+1] - c[i]) / (3 * h[i])

    return a[1:], b, c[1:], d

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.profile(False)
cdef np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=1] searchsorted_merge(
    double[:] a,
    double[:] b,
    bint sort_b,
):
    cdef:
        np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=1] idx = np.zeros(b.size, dtype=np.int64)
        np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=1] ib
        int pa = 0
        int pb = 0

    if sort_b:
        ib = np.argsort(b)

    while pb < len(b):
        if pa < len(a) and a[pa] < (b[ib[pb]] if sort_b else b[pb]):
            pa += 1
        else:
            idx[pb] = pa
            pb += 1
    return idx

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.profile(False)
cdef double[:] func_spline(
    double[:] x,
    np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=1] ix,
    double[:] x0,
    double[:] a,
    double[:] b,
    double[:] c,
    double[:] d,
):
    cdef:
        int n = x.size
        double[:] dx = np.zeros(n)
        double[:] spline = np.zeros(n)
        int i, ixi

    for i from 0 <= i < n by 1:
        ixi = ix[i]
        dx[i] = x[i] - x0[ixi+1]
        spline[i] = a[ixi] + (b[ixi] + (c[ixi] + d[ixi] * dx[i]) * dx[i]) * dx[i]

    return spline

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.profile(False)
cpdef double[:] piece_wise_spline(
    double[:] x,
    double[:] x0,
    double[:] a,
    double[:] b,
    double[:] c,
    double[:] d,
):
    cdef:
        np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=1] ix
        double[:] y
    
    ix = searchsorted_merge(x0[1:-1], x, True)
    y = func_spline(x, ix, x0, a, b, c, d)
    return y

cdef class CubicSpline():
    def __cinit__(self, double[:] x0, double[:] y0):
        self.x0 = x0
        self.a, self.b, self.c, self.d = calculate_spline_params(x0, y0)

    def __call__(self, x):
        x = np.atleast_1d(x)
        return self._call(x)
    
    cpdef _call(self, double[:] x):
        return piece_wise_spline(
            x, self.x0, self.a, self.b, self.c, self.d,
        )
```

I compare this with a `numba` implementation (`interpolate.py`)

```
@numba.njit(
    cache = True,
    fastmath = True,
)
def calc_spline_params(
    x,
    y,
):
    n = x.size - 1
    a = y.copy()
    h = x[1:] - x[:-1]
    alpha = 3 * ((a[2:] - a[1:-1]) / h[1:] - (a[1:-1] - a[:-2]) / h[:-1])
    c = np.zeros(n+1)
    ell, mu, z = np.ones(n+1), np.zeros(n), np.zeros(n+1)
    for i in range(1, n):
        ell[i] = 2 * (x[i+1] - x[i-1]) - h[i-1] * mu[i-1]
        mu[i] = h[i] / ell[i]
        z[i] = (alpha[i-1] - h[i-1] * z[i-1]) / ell[i]
    for i in range(n-1, -1, -1):
        c[i] = z[i] - mu[i] * c[i+1]
    b = (a[1:] - a[:-1]) / h + (c[:-1] + 2 * c[1:]) * h / 3
    d = np.diff(c) / (3 * h)

    return a[1:], b, c[1:], d
    
@numba.njit(
    cache = True,
    fastmath = True,
)
def func_spline(
    x,
    ix,
    x0,
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d,
):
    dx = x - x0[1:][ix]
    return a[ix] + (b[ix] + (c[ix] + d[ix] * dx) * dx) * dx

@numba.njit(
    cache = True,
    fastmath = True,
)
def searchsorted_merge(
    a,
    b,
    sort_b,
):
    idx = np.zeros((len(b),), dtype = np.int64)
    if sort_b:
        ib = np.argsort(b)
    pa, pb = 0, 0
    while pb < len(b):
        if pa < len(a) and a[pa] < (b[ib[pb]] if sort_b else b[pb]):
            pa += 1
        else:
            idx[pb] = pa
            pb += 1
    return idx
    
@numba.njit(
    cache = True,
    fastmath = True,
)
def piece_wise_spline(
    x,
    x0,
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d,
):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    xsh = x.shape
    x = x.ravel()
    ix = searchsorted_merge(x0[1 : -1], x, True)
    y = func_spline(x, ix, x0, a, b, c, d)
    y = np.ascontiguousarray(y).reshape(xsh)
    return y

def cubic_spline(
    x0,
    y0,
):
    a, b, c, d = calc_spline_params(x0, y0)

    @numba.njit()
    def f(x):
        return piece_wise_spline(x, x0, a, b, c, d)

    return f
```

Here is a sample benchmark of the code:

```
import numpy as np

from interp import CubicSpline
from interpolate import cubic_spline
import scipy.interpolate as spip


x = np.linspace(0, 100, 10000)
y = np.sin(x)

cython_interp = CubicSpline(x, y)
numba_interp = cubic_spline(x, y)
scipy_interp = spip.CubicSpline(x, y)

%timeit cython_interp(0.8) # 7.91 µs ± 76.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
%timeit numba_interp(0.8) # 2.1 µs ± 155 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
%timeit scipy_interp(0.8) # 4.36 µs ± 191 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Ideally, I'd like to get the `cython` implementation to be as performant as `numba`.

Comment: This submission is about performance. You currently have a window of opportunity to revise the OP to reveal what [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase) in/out workloads matter to you, how you conduct benchmark timings, and maybe even offer representative app code, here or via GitHub. The window closes when someone posts an Answer. Also, the occasional link to https://godbolt.org wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I added another implementation as well as benchmarking between the different implementations which shows the usage which I need.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between this and e.g. [`CubicSpline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html)?

Comment: Ah, I see you've included it in your benchmarks

Comment: I am not sure about the exact implementation of `scipy`, but I assume it must be something similar - there aren't that many ways to do a cubic spline after all.